# React - Removing Item from state causes memo component to re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, I store chat messages in my Redux state in the format: `{"chatId": {messageKey: {message object }}}`.

I call `useSelector` on my Chat page in order to retrieve the messages:

```
const chatMessages = useSelector((state) => state.messages.messagesData[chatId], {equalityFn: shallowEqual}) || {}
```

I then loop over all of these `chatMessages` and display an indivudal `ChatMessage` component for each message. `ChatMessage` is wrapped in `memo`, as I noticed when a new message was added to the state for a chat, all previous messages would re-render even though the contents were the same. Here is the code for this below:

```
  // Looping over chat messages
  {Object.keys(storedUsers).length !== 0  && chatId && Object.keys(chatMessages).length !== 0  &&
                    Object.values(chatMessages).map((messageObj, index) => {
                         let replyTo
                         if (messageObj.replyTo) replyTo = chatMessages && Object.values(chatMessages).filter((m) => m.messageId === messageObj.replyTo)
                         return <ChatMessage replyTo={replyTo} storedUsers={storedUsers}  userData={userData} setReplyTo={setReplyTo} chatId={chatId} key={index} messageObj={messageObj} newChatData={newChatData} handleDeleteMessage={handleDeleteMessage} />
                    })
   }
```

`ChatMessage` component code:

```
// Custom equality function to determine whether a message should actually re-render
function arePropsEqual(oldProps, newProps) {
    return JSON.stringify(oldProps.messageObj) === JSON.stringify(newProps.messageObj)
}

// Message component displayed for each message
const ChatMessage = memo(({messageObj, replyTo, newChatData, storedUsers, handleDeleteMessage, chatId, setReplyTo, userData}) => {
    if (messageObj.admin === true) return 
    if (messageObj.hidden && messageObj.hidden === true) return


const sentById = messageObj.sentBy

return ( 
    <div style={{marginTop: 50}}>
        <div className='d-flex flex-row'>

            {messageObj && messageObj.uploadUrl && messageObj.fileType === "image" && <img src={messageObj.uploadUrl && messageObj.uploadUrl} width={300} height={300} />}
            {messageObj && messageObj.uploadUrl && messageObj.fileType === "video" && 
                <>
    
                    <video controls style={{width: 400, height: 300}}>
                        <source src={messageObj.uploadUrl} />
                    </video>
                    {/* <ReactPlayer playing={true} controls pip 
                            light url={messageObj.uploadUrl} /> */}
    
                </>
            }
    
    </div>
    )
}, arePropsEqual)
```

When a new message is pushed to a chats messages state, the equality function returns true, and previous messages are not re-rendered as their contents did not change (confirmed by using `react-profiler`)

However when deleting a specific message with a `messageKey` from a chat, the equality function no longer works and returns false causing all previous messages to be re-rendered, however the previous messages did not change.

Here is the redux logic to remove a message from a particular chat:

```
  // Remove a particular message with a messageId from a  particular chats messages
  removeMessageState: (state, action) => {
     const existingMessages = state.messagesData
     const {chatId, messageId} = action.payload;

     delete existingMessages[chatId][messageId]
     state.messagesData = existingMessages
 },
```

Why do all previous messages get re-rendered after I remove a message from a chat, however when adding a message to the chat, all previous messages do not re-render.  Is there a flaw in the `equality function`, or perhaps the redux function is causing the issue? Thanks.